# How to access database on application start in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

I want to create a scheduler and get cron expressions in the database during start up. But I get an error "Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application".

I think the problem is with using play.api.Play.current but I need it for DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>

Do I need to inject db connection? How do I do that? Or Am I using a wrong approach? Please advice.

This is what I have so far..

**Application.conf**

```
play.modules.enabled += "tasks.MyRecurrentTaskModule"
```

**MyRecurrentTaskModule.scala**

```
class MyRecurrentTaskModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[RecurrentTask]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

@Singleton
class RecurrentTask @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {

    lifecycle.addStopHook{ () =>

        Future.successful(actorSystem.shutdown())
    }
    // Error when I access db
    val schedule = models.ScheduleTable.getSchedule(1)
    ...

}
```

**ScheduleTable.scala**

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

case class ScheduleTable (
  ...
) {
}

object ScheduleTable {
val scheduleParser = {
  ...
  }
}

def getSchedule (ScheduleId: Int): Option[ScheduleTable] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("""
          select * from SCHEDULE_TABLE s
          where s.ScheduleId = {sid}
          """)
      .on('sid -> ScheduleId)
      .as(ScheduleTable.scheduleParser.singleOpt)
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it now.. First I need to change my model to object from class(Play 2.5) and to Inject DBApi. BTW I renamed it from ScheduleTable to ScheduleTableService to avoid error

**ScheduleTable.scala**

```
@javax.inject.Singleton
class ScheduleTableSevice @Inject() (dbapi: DBApi) {

  private val db = dbapi.database("default")

  val scheduleParser = {
    ...
    }
  }

  def getSchedule (ScheduleId: Int): Option[ScheduleTable] = {
    db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("""
          select * from SCHEDULE_TABLE s
          where s.ScheduleId = {sid}
          """)
      .on('sid -> ScheduleId)
      .as(scheduleParser.singleOpt)
    }
  }
```

**MyRecurrentTaskModule.scala**

Then Inject it to MyRecurrentTaskModule.scala

```
class RecurrentTask @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, scheduleService: TxScheduleSevice) {
```